# How to measure and interpret diversity index of discrete probability distribution?

Tags: entropy

I need to measure the diversity of discrete probability distribution, for example, consider we have a question asked to 10 students, 9 of them answered yes, and 1 only answered now. this gives distribution of {0.9:yes, 0.1:now}, note the classification is variable, it might be multiple choices, is there a measure to quantify diversity?? i used shannon earlier but i could't interpret the result to understandable form like percentage.

Comment: What do you understand by "diversity"? What do you want to do/know exactly?

Comment: i mean by diversity, how far opinions consensus from each other? do you think Simpson index is better ?